# How to auto increment data on new record insertion

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I would like to add a user defined column which will auto increment on new record insertion, how should I do this? so that it runs on h2, mysql

```
@Entity public class Parent {

@OneToMany List<Child> children;

}

@Entity public class Child {
    int sortOrder;
}

e.g. Parent1 has Child{1, 2, 3}
Parent2 has {1, 2}
```

Note: Values within each Parent needs to be auto incremented not outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Id type as identity, and the DB tbale should handle the Identity insertion.

sample,

```
<id
            name="dayTypeId"
            column="Day_Type_ID"
            type="int">

            <generator class="identity">
            </generator>
        </id>
```

Answer (score 0):

The database handles this, not Hibernate.  You need auto_increment surrogate primary keys in your tables.